# How to View Dask Daskboard in Dask Gateway when using a private IP address/VPC?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dask, dask-distributed, dask-kubernetes, dask-gateway

We deployed Dask Gateway on Kubernetes on Google Cloud Platform. We are currently using an internal TCP load balancer to expose the traefik proxy for security purposes. Our users are able to create a client connection to the cluster generated through Dask Gateway just fine. But because we are now using an internal load balancer on a private VPC, the link to the dashboard is no longer accessible. How do we expose this dashboard link?

What I am attempting to do is to create a separate external load balancer for the Dask Dashboard and then in the cluster config, somehow point that to the external load balancer. But I'm not quite sure how to do this in the kubernetes helm chart.

Thanks in advance.